# Getting "#NAME" from SharePoint Survey calculated column

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, survey

In the results for a Survey done in SharePoint 2013 (survey list - type that I'm "inheriting", if you know what I mean).

I noticed we're getting "#NAME" in some of the areas we're pulling down.

Here are the details of the survey and the field in question:

- The columns in the survey where we're getting #NAME are calculated
  columns based upon some of the answers in the other questions.
- These answers fields are CHOICE columns (radio buttons) ranged from 1-9.
- The calculation looks something like this:

  `=AVERAGE(0+[Item A value],0+[Item B value],0+[Item C value],0+[Item D value],0+[Item E value],0+[Item F value],0+[Item G value])`

Based on this information, what do you see that could be causing the error?

Comment: To understand your issue better, please provide some screenshots about this issue and also provide these choice field settings.